# Phonegap Cordova - How to pause download and resume from downloaded size

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova file-transfer plugin for download file from server.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

I need to implement pause feature with incremental download.

Is it possible to do this with this plugin?

Comment: you have to handle it in your code.
use localstorage to remember the last downloaded file,downloaded percentage and to be downloaded files.
user pause,resume event handling to handle pause activities when app goes background/foreground.

Comment: Hi Mohammed Imran. thank you for your comment. It is a single file not many files. I need to pause the single file download.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I was wondering the same

Answer (score 0):

We've been using this https://github.com/IllusionVK/cordova-plugin-pause-resume-download-1 in production for the past few years.  It works wonderfully and allow for situations like swapping between 4g and WiFi in the middle of a download.

We regularly download both small 1-4mb and large 100-200mb files with it.  It relies upon `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` and adds extra code in to that plugins code at the time of build.

The only thing to be careful of is that it normally needs a rebuild of the platform so that it gets added correctly.  It will show `PRD replace Success !!!` (which indicates that it has modified the cordova-plugin-file-transfer files) for the first build and then `PRD replace Failed !!!` for every build after that, which is normal behaviour.